# How to fix column count doesnt match value in Java netbeans

Tags: java, sql, netbeans, count

I made a Java application on netbeans about ranking the vikor method,
but when going to save the table data to the database, an error appears saying that the count table is mismatch.

I have tried changing the syntax and database settings. But still

Is there anything I missed?
Anything about storing data from table calculations directly to the database?
This is my code:

```
public void cariperingkat(){
    try {

   LinkedList mm=new LinkedList();
        ResultSet res3 = conn.ambilData("select * from bobot");
           tabelmodelPERINGKAT();
           while (res3.next()){
                       mm.add(res3.getString(1));
                       mm.add(res3.getString(2));
                       mm.add(res3.getString(3));
                       mm.add(res3.getString(4));
           }
        for (int t = 0; t < jTable2.getRowCount(); t++) {

        String sql = "delete from data_alternatif WHERE nama= nama";
           conn.simpanData(sql);
        }
        for (int x = 0; x < jTable2.getRowCount(); x++) {
           double r1;
           double r2;
           double r3;
           double r4;
           double w;
            r1=(Float.valueOf(jTable2.getValueAt(x, 1).toString())*Float.valueOf(mm.get(0).toString()));
            r2=(Float.valueOf(jTable2.getValueAt(x, 2).toString())*Float.valueOf(mm.get(1).toString()));
            r3=(Float.valueOf(jTable2.getValueAt(x, 3).toString())*Float.valueOf(mm.get(2).toString()));
            r4=(Float.valueOf(jTable2.getValueAt(x, 4).toString())*Float.valueOf(mm.get(3).toString()));
            w=r1+r2+r3+r4;
        String sql = "insert into data_alternatif  values"+
         "('"+jTable2.getValueAt(x, 0).toString()+"', "+
         "'"+w+"')";
           conn.simpanData(sql);
        }
        tabelmodelPERINGKAT();
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, ex);
    }
   }
```

[image: table structure for bobot]

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.  Please provide the table structure so the problem is more easily diagnosed.

Comment: updated, please look